# If A,B,C are elements of sigma algebra prove the following:

Tags: probability

1. |P(A)-P(B)|<=P(A(simetric difference)B)

now, i tried: since A simdif B = AunionB \ AintersectB and AintersectB subset of  AunionB then P(AsimdifB)<=P(AunionB)-P(AintersectB)= P(A)+P(B)-2P(AintersectB) now this seems obvious to me, but i don't know how to formalise it properly.

2. |P(AintersectB)-P(AintersectC)|<=P(BsimdifC)
   3.P(AsimB)<=P(AsimC)+P(CsimB)
3. Does there exist A,B,C elements of sigma algebra so that: P(A)-P(C)>3/4 , P(AsimB)+P(BsimC)<2/3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $P$ is a probability measure?  The symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$ is defined as $(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$

So, $|P(A) - P(B)| = |P((A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B)) - P((B \setminus A) \cup (B \cap A)|
\\ = |P(A \setminus B) + P(A \cap B) - P(B \setminus A) - P(A \cap B)|
\\ = |P(A \setminus B) - P(B \setminus A)|
\\ \le P(A \setminus B) + P (B \setminus A) = P( (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A))$,